# pasar parametos con PHP

Tags: php

Estoy intentando que al dar click en una imagen pase los parametros que necesito a la otra pagina.

```
<a href="todoeventos.php?variable=<?php print $variable ["imagenes"]?>">
```

Con esto consigo pasar la imagen al otro archivo php,pero necesito pasar tambien nombre_evento localizacion y precio.

he probado hacer algo asi pero no funciona

```
<a href="todoeventos.php?variable=<?php print $variable ["imagenes"]?>dos=<?php print $dos ["imagenes"]?>">
```

y este es todo mi codigo

```
    <div class="row">
<?php
while ($variable = $consultaimg->fetch_assoc())
{

  ?>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">


      <a href="todoeventos.php?variable=<?php print $variable ["imagenes"]?>">

        <img src="<?php print $variable["imagenes"]?>" style="width:100%">
        <div class="caption">
          <p >Nombre evento: <?php print $variable ["nombre_evento"]?></p>
          <p>Localizacion:<?php print $variable ["localizacion"]?></p>
          <p>Precio de la entrada: <?php print $variable ["precio"]?></p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <?php

}
```

?>

Comment: Coloca el símbolo `&` antes de la palabra dos así: <a href="todoeventos.php?variable=<?php print $variable ["imagenes"]?>&dos=<?php print $dos ["imagenes"]?>"> de modo que se concatenen los parámetros. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes pasar todos los parametros por la URL, usando el metodo GET, ejemplo:

```
<a href="destino.php?variable1=valor1&variable2=valor2&...">Mi enlace</a>
```

Método GET: [Un array asociativo de variables pasado al script actual vía parámetros URL.](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.get.php)

Te quedaria así:

```
<a href="todoeventos.php?variable=<?php echo $variable["imagenes"]?>&localizacion=<?php echo $variable["localizacion"] ?>&precio=<?php echo $variable["precio"] ?>">
```

Esto lo recibes en tu archivo **todoeventos.php**

```
$imagenes = $_GET["imagenes"];
$localizacion= $_GET["localizacion"];
$precio= $_GET["precio"];
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: gracias,ahora con ese codigo consegui cargar los demas datos,pero ahora la imagen no se carga xD hice un var dump y devuelve null

Comment: Me alegra mucho que te sirva Nuria. Te sugiero que mires https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  para formular bien tu pregunta, ya que se dio solución al problema y ahora planteas algo más, te sugiero abrir una nueva pregunta y calificar la respuesta que te ha servido, para que alguien más pueda beneficiarse, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Al pasar más de un parámetro de una página a otra es necesario agregar entre cada uno de ellos un `&`

```
 http://url.php?parametro1=valor1&parametro2=valor2
```

Quedando de esta forma tu código PHP / HTML:

```
 <a href="todoeventos.php?variable=<?php print $variable ["imagenes"]?>&dos=<?php print $dos ["imagenes"]?>">
```

Comment: cuando ago eso,al dar click a la imagen no me hace nada,no me redirige al otro archivo php

Answer (score 0):

Tu enlace quedaría así por ejemplo: (para ir juntando variables se usa la "&")

```
<a href="post.php?id=123&date=2018-02-20"> Link al post 123 </a>
```

Y en tu post.php para consumir el dato, debes recibirlo por GET así:

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['id']; // en este caso imprimirá "123"
    echo $_GET['date']; // en este caso imprimirá "2018-02-20"
?>
```

(aunque luego debes sanitizar todos los datos recibidos por GET para evitar inyecciones SQL y demás)